# Convert python dictionaries into MATLAB

Tags: python, regex, matlab, parsing

I have a list of python dictionaries saved text files in such form:

`TEST BayesianSearch: Fold 1 results: {'AUC': 0.02361111111111111, 'precision': 0.012, 'recall': 0.0034607372805101266, 'map': 0.006173611111111111, 'NDCG': 0.0038391623343341052, 'MRR': 0.024472222222222218, 'F1': 0.005372169077405249, 'HR': 0.048, 'ARHR': 0.02458333333333333}`

`TEST BayesianSearch: Fold 2 results: {'AUC': 0.034277777777777775, 'precision': 0.016416666666666666, 'recall': 0.003939761087163834, 'map': 0.009020833333333329, 'NDCG': 0.0052255728628175955, 'MRR': 0.035861111111111094, 'F1': 0.006354527945317168, 'HR': 0.06566666666666666, 'ARHR': 0.0359722222222222}`

In MATLAB,

- How can I find starting with `TEST BayesianSearch: Fold i results`, where i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?
- From those lines, how can I get the numbers out?

Comment: This sounds like a pure Matlab question, not a Python one at all, since your data are saved in a txt format and you want to load and analyze them in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The task can be accomplished nicely using Matlab's [regular expressions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), which supports **named capturing groups**. 
Using named capturing groups in Matlab's is handy, because regexp automatically creates a structure for you, with the named capturing groups as fields, when using the correct keyword `names`.

For character vector *str* and regular expression *expression* with `names` keyword specified, the documentation states:

> If str and expression are both character vectors or string scalars, the output is a 1-by-n structure array, where n is the number of matches. The structure field names correspond to the token names.

The regex I used for the task is the following:

`(?:TEST.*?(?=\d\.))(?<AUC>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)(?<precision>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)(?<recall>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)(?<map>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<NDCG>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<MMR>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*\d':\s)(?<F1>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<HR>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<ARHR>\d*\.\d*)`

The above expression captures all of the numbers in named capture groups. You can find a live demonstration of the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/fCX6FF/1/).

---

**Regular expression explanation:**

- `(?:TEST.*?(?=\d\.))` Match but do not capture TEST, and use a positive lookahead to match everything up to the first number which is followed by a decimal point.
- `(?<AUC>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `AUC`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, lower case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<precision>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `precision`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, lower case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<recall>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `recall`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, lower case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<map>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `map`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, upper case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<NDCG>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `NDCG`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, upper case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<MMR>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `MMR`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*\d':\s)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, higher case ASCII characters and colon. This is then followed by a digit, a apostrophe, colon and whitespace.
- `(?<F1>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `F1`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, upper case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<HR>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `HR`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.
- `(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)` Match but do not capture everything in the character class, which includes: a comma, whitespace, a apostrophe, upper case ASCII characters and colon.
- `(?<ARHR>\d*\.\d*)` Capturing group named `ARHR`, captures digits, a decimal point, and more digits.

---

**Matlab implementation:**

Read your text file with [fileread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) and implement the regular expression.

The keyword `names` is used to return the *name* and *text* of each named token.

```
data = fileread('mytext.txt');
alldata = regexp(data,"(?:TEST.*?(?=\d\.))(?<AUC>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)(?<precision>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)(?<recall>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'a-z:]*)(?<map>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<NDCG>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<MMR>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*\d':\s)(?<F1>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<HR>\d*\.\d*)(?:[,\s'A-Z:]*)(?<ARHR>\d*\.\d*)",'names')
```

The output of the implemented code is then a *1×2 struct array* with the named capture groups as fields.

`alldata(1)` :

```
AUC: '0.02361111111111111'
precision: '0.012'
recall: '0.0034607372805101266'
map: '0.006173611111111111'
NDCG: '0.0038391623343341052'
MMR: '0.024472222222222218'
F1: '0.005372169077405249'
HR: '0.048'
ARHR: '0.02458333333333333'
```

`alldata(2)` :

```
AUC: '0.034277777777777775'
precision: '0.016416666666666666'
recall: '0.003939761087163834'
map: '0.009020833333333329'
NDCG: '0.0052255728628175955'
MMR: '0.035861111111111094'
F1: '0.006354527945317168'
HR: '0.06566666666666666'
ARHR: '0.0359722222222222'
```

To access your data simply use dot notation, for example `alldata(1).AUC`. 
Please note that for numerical calculations you will need to convert the fields from character vectors to doubles.